# i18n translation with CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

## Context

I want to translate my app in french and english. I followed exactly the [CakePHP 3 documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#setting-up-translations) but it is not working.

## What I did so far

For my development, I'm using a vagrant box to easily get up and running with CakePHP 3. This box is named [vagrant-chef](https://github.com/friendsofcake/vagrant-chef)

### /config/bootstrap.php

I modified the line 100 to use french as the default language.

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'fr_CA');
```

### /src/Controller/PagesController

I added this method to the default PagesController

```
public function initialize() {
    I18n::locale('en');
}
```

### /src/Template/Pages/home.ctp

I added these 2 lines

```
    <?php echo __('Hey, bonjour'); ?>
    <?php echo __('Je teste la traduction'); ?>
```

### .pot file generation

From the terminal, I input this command `bin/cake i18n extract`. CakePHP created 2 files in `/src/Locale/`. Those files are `cake.pot` and `default.pot`. I translated the default.pot file like that:

```
...
msgid "Hey, bonjour"
msgstr "Hey, hello"
...
```

### Locales directory structure

The `/src/Locale` file looks like this now:

```
/en
   /default.pot
```

Despite my attempts to translate my app, I didn't get anything working. I supposed it was a Cache problem, so I deleted the files in `/tmp/cache/persistent/`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.pot` generated by `cake i18n extract` is the template file. Your per language files needs to be `.po`. So as per your example it should be `src/Locale/en/default.po`.

Comment: Thanks, it was so simple... I can't accept your answer until 7 minutes. :)