# cakephp doesn't translate with .po

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I've got the same issue than Richer [i18n translation with CakePHP 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822817/i18n-translation-with-cakephp-3), but even with the given solution (using .po file instead of .pot), CakePHP refuse to translate. 
In my differents attempts, I :

- double-checked, triple-checked, quadruple-checked the directories and files (src/Locale/en/default.po and src/Locale/fr_CA/default.po), and deleted (or not) the fr_CA directory,
- reproduced step-by-step (with or without copy-paste) what Richer made,
- deleted (or not) the generated-by-poedit default.mo file,
- of course deleted the /temp/cache/persistent after each attempt
- check with a phpinfo() in my controller's code than intl.default_locale was swiched from "fr_CA" to "en" in the local value column (there is "no value" in the master value column) and that GetText was enabled (even if I didn't found any trace of GetText in the CakePHP code, but that's an other story)

btw, there is the full src/Locale/en/default.po

```
# LANGUAGE translation of CakePHP Application
# Copyright YEAR NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PROJECT VERSION\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2015-08-07 08:21+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2015-08-07 10:22+0100\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n>1);\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.5.4\n"
"Language: en\n"

#: Template/Pages/index1.ctp:1
msgid "Hey, bonjour"
msgstr "hello"
```

But my page still shows an untranslated "Hey, bonjour"...

I probably miss a very very obvious thing, but which one ?

Thanks in advance

Yvan

Comment: I change the local in an initialize() function. I've tried in the PagesController.Display() function as well.

`    public function initialize() {
        I18n::locale('en');
        debug('Killroy was here');
    }
`

Comment: I answer to myself : the .po files where readable (mod 644), but the directory which containt them was'nt executable !
So, PHP coundn't find them...

What a noob...